# Both web3.eth.accounts.create and web3.eth.personal.newAccount don't work

Tags: web3js, go-ethereum

I already know what is the difference between `accounts.create()` and `personal.newAccount()` .

My Geth setting is like this,

```
--rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3"
```

`web3.eth.getBalance()`runs very well.

But both `web3.eth.accounts.create()` and `web3.eth.personal.newAccount()` don't work.

No any error messages. Just no response.

What can I do for this situation? Help me please.

Here is the example code.

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); // Geth RPC is working.
...
const password = "test1234";
const account = web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password); // not work.
console.log(account); // not work. not print anything.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using web3-1.x.x if not let me know.

Answer:

`web3.eth.personal.newAccount` returns a `Promise<string>` you need to either `await` it or `.then` it - docs here https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545")); // Geth RPC is working.
...
const password = "test1234";
web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password)
                           .then(account => console.log(account));
```

web3.eth.accounts.create() is a promise as well so

```
web3.eth.accounts.create()
                 .then(console.log);
```